# Can I assign a static IP to my smart phone?

Tags: networking, ip, cellular-network

Is it possible to configure/purchase/etc a static ip address for a mobile device that holds this address across geographic locations and types of coverage (wifi, LTE, 4G, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually configure your mobile to static ip address, but the disadvantage is that when the router seen two ip address the 2nd ip address cannot connect